# Is there a way to force a PWA to stay in offline mode via a toggle in-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

Recently just started building a PWA and I thought a useful feature for privacy and control could be a toggle on the site that allows the user to force the site to remain in offline mode until the toggle is pressed again. After some research, however, I am unable to find any way to accomplish this, anybody has any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, have a look a service workers..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: To add to @Keith's comment. In the Service Worker you can intercept every `fetch` request that is being made. In there you can decide wether to actually fetch new data or use data from the cache. So online vs offline.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thank you for the reply, I have looked into this but am unsure how I would be able to tell the service worker my app is in online/offline mode as it seems service workers do not have access to DOM elements or localStorage?

Comment: @BenCooper the service worker indeed cannot access the DOM or localStorage. However, it can receive messages from the main thread that can tell you if you are in online or offline mode with the [`message`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/message_event) event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a toggle or checkbox on in the HTML from where you will control the state. This input element will control wether offline mode is on or off. The value of that input has to be send to the service worker who then can decide what to do whenever a `fetch` request is being made.

```html
<input id="check-offline" type="checkbox" name="offline-mode">
<label for="check-offline">Offline mode</label>
```

In your main thread select the button and register your Service Worker. Whenever the worker has registered successfully add an event listener to the input you've created up here and listen for a `change`. In the handler of the event listener use the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/message_event) function on the worker to send the checked value to the worker.

```js
const offLineToggle = document.getElementById('check-offline');

navigator.serviceWorker.register('/path/to/service-worker.js').then(registration => {
  const serviceWorker = registration.active;
  if (serviceWorker !== null) {
    offLineToggle.addEventListener('change', event => {
      serviceWorker.postMessage({
        name: 'offlineMode',
        value: event.target.checked
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Then in your Service Worker script create an object (or variable) to store the current settings in. In the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` listen for the `message` event. This is the receiving end for the `postMessage` function. Here you can handle the data and update the settings for the offlineMode.

Then add another event listener and listen for the `fetch` event, which will be fired whenever a `fetch` request has been made from the main thread. In the event handler check if the offline mode is on or off and handle accordingly.

```js
const settings = {
  offlineMode: false
};

self.addEventListener('message', { data } => {
  const { name, value } = data;
  if (settings.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    settings[name] = value;
  }
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const { offlineMode } = settings;
  if (offlineMode === true) {
    // Force return data from cache.
  } else {
    // Get fresh data from the server.
  }
});
```

This all is an outline of how it could work. Read up on the [Using Service Workers article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) to see how you can access the cache and control the data that is being send to the client.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for that I appreciate it a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Service workers have access to indexedDB. Alternatively, DOM has access to the cache storage. 
You could cache a key "offline" either in indexedDB or cache storage, and check the value on the fetch event.